# Robohelp 10 Changing URL does not change content

Tags: robohelp

I am having trouble navigating with a project that I regenerated from an old project for the benefit of the Chrome TOC showing on the left. Now I have the problem of the lack of navigation via the URL. When I change the URL it does not change the content of the window as shown below:

[image]

Navigating to "Affected By MU" in the URL does not yield the expected result of having the page showing with that title. Navigating via the browser address field does not affect the page as it did in the old project before I regenerated it. How do I recreate this functionality?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out myself I removed the "# < id=0" at the end and it navigates to the correct page. For some reason this was in logic when the hyperlink is pressed that id is attached to the end of the URL.